# ora-00939 error in reporting services, SSRS

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report, Oracle is my backend and am using this following query for dataset of my second parameter.

```
select distinct  X
from  v_stf_sec_user_staffing_center usc
where usc.center_group_id in  (
 select distinct center_group_id from  V_T_STAFFING_CENTER_GROUP scg
where  INSTR(','||REPLACE(:PI_REGION_LIST,' ')||',', ','||scg.group_abbreviation||',') > 0)
and usc.nt_user_name=:PI_NT_USER_NAME
```

Here `PI_REGION_LIST` is a multivalued parameter of string type.
and `PI_NT_USER_NAME` is a default string  valued parameter

This query works fine when I try to execute in manually in the Data tab, also in the Oracle tool. But when I run the report in SSRS and select more than 3 values for the parameter `PI_REGION_LIST` the report throws an error on this dataset

> ora-00939  error,too many arguments for function.

I am not able to figure out the error here.

Please help me with an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The [REPLACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm#i78608) function takes three string parameters, the last being optional.

The [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292.aspx) says a multi-valued parameter has the following restriction
"The query must use an IN clause to specify the parameter."

If you don't actually need to do the REPLACE to get rid of spaces, you should be able to do something like

```
WHERE scg.group_abbreviation in (:PI_REGION_LIST)
```